# Boolean value in when section using Drools 7.21

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to migrate Drools from version 5.2 to 7.21. I rebuilded the code to KIE API and all looked fine, but now I get a problem in DRL files. In "when" section in Drools file I need to use statement "finished != true". In v5.2 it worked fine, but in v7.21 not...

My code:

```
rule"..."
  when
    element : Operation( person.id == $person.getId(), finished != true )
  then
    (...)
  end
```

I've done some tests, and the results are wierd:

- **finished != true** -> it doesn't work and all objects with "finished == true" are in the results too
- **finished == false** -> like above
- **finished** -> it's working fine and only the objects with "finished == true" are in the results
- **finished == true** -> like above

I need to use **finished != true** or something similar. How can I fix it? Is it an error in new Drools version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which is working for me. If someone have better way to do it, please share it here.

```
rule"..."
  when
    $booleanTrue : Boolean(booleanValue == true) from 1 == 1
    element : Operation( person.id == $person.getId(), finished != $booleanTrue )
  then
    (...)
  end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, What's the type of "finished", have you defined it as boolean?

Comment: Yes, in my java class field "finished" is defined as a boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below:

```
rule"..."
  when
    element : Operation( person.id == $person.getId(), finished)
  then
    (...)
  end
```

Or

```
rule"..."
  when
    element : Operation( person.id == $person.getId(), !finished)
  then
    (...)
  end
```